# What is the difference between Genetic Algorithm and Iterated Local Search Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm basically trying to use Genetic Algorithm or Iterated Local Search Algorithm to get an optimal solution for a question.Can someone please explain what is the basic difference between these two algorithms and is there any situations where one of them is better than the other?

Comment: These heuristics typically don't find optimal solutions (even if they do by accident, you don't know if the solutions are optimal). They find good solutions quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start from the second question. I believe that there is no way to determine a better algorithm for a given problem without any trials and tests. The behavior of an algorithm heavily depends on problem's properties. If we are talking about complex problems with hundreds and thousands of variables, it's just too difficult to predict anything. I'm not talking about your engineer's intuition, some deep problem understanding, previous experience, etc, they are not really measurable.

The main difference between global and local search is quite straightforward - local search considers just one or a few of possible solutions at a single point of time and it tries to improve them with some modifications. Thus, each iteration it considers just a small portion of a search space (=local neighboorhood). Global search tries to take into account whole problem with all its parameters at the same time. For example, [PSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) samples huge amount of candidates and tries to move all of them into the global optimum's direction using some simple formula.